# One abstract rails model

Tags: sql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In rails/activerecord, is it possible to have three ruby classes, two of which inherit from one main class, and then have two separate tables for pots and pans. Like so...

```
class Tupperware < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Pot < Tupperware

end

class Pan < Tupperware

end
```

and the advantage would be that I could use the Tupperware.find() method, and a few other things, without having to customize for each different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know for sure it works with mongoid – I've done it myself a couple of times. I'm not sure if this would work in relative database engine...
But you're actually asking a question you could answer yourself, by just trying to do what you said.

*[In response to OP's comment]:*

I'm just saying you should do a test rails application using a relative db, such as mySQL or SQLite and define your models exactly the way you think.

I have an abstract model I use in my application. It's working perfectly and the `find()` method works just as you'd expect, but I'm working on Mongoid, so I don't use `ActiveResource` and can't say for sure if this will work for you. The only thing you can do is try.

Here, take a look at this excerpt from my code:
https://gist.github.com/ellmo/5262681

Comment: Not entirely... I was wondering if there was any way I could have separate DB tables, but use one find() method.